# Github error "fatal: remote origin already exists."

Tags: git, github, terminal

I'm trying to follow a bottega tutorial but I ran into this error. I have looked at other similar questions but none of the answers seem to work for me. I'm using rails 5 but when I try the following line it gives me the error

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyName/my_view_tool.git
```

I was wondering if anyone new how to fix this?
One of the common answers I saw was the following but it did not work for me.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MyName/my_view_tool.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already add a remote named `origin`, find your `.git` folder in project root path and edit the `config` file in `.git` folder, replace the origin url to GitHub url, config file like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = [ORIGIN_URL_HERE]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up `.git/config` in your favourite editor and manually change the url of the remote repository, it's under `[remote "origin"]`.